# Given a Model enum, how to create a radio button group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :status [:banned, :registered, :trial, :pending]
end
```

On my edit page, I want to show a list of 4 radio buttons and pre-select the radio button that is currently set for a user.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :status, User.statuses, :first, :first %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

[Ref](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:collection_check_boxes)

Answer (score 1):

Rails creates a class method using the pluralized attribute name when you use `enum`. The method returns a `key value pair` of strings you've defined and what integers they map to. So, you could do something like this:

```
<% User.status.keys.each do |status| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :status, status %>
  <%= f.label status.to_sym %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use `User.statuses.each_key`, which is faster than `keys.each`. Also, is it necessary to convert the status into a symbol? `f.label status.to_sym`. I think that's redundant.

Comment: Use `<%= f.label "status_#{status}" %>` to generate proper label 'for' attributes